# CakePHP admin prefix with dash?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I would like my admin prefix to be admin-manage, but later, when how can I define function in my controller?

I can't write function like this :

```
admin-manage_add(){
      //some code here
}
```

I have added to my core.php this :

```
 Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin-manage'));
```

How can I manage this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify the [default prefixrouting routes](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/950/Prefix-Routing) and include them manually in your *routes.php*.

```
Router::connect("/admin-manage", array('controller' => 'client','action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect("/admin-manage/:controller", array('action' => 'index', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
Router::connect("/admin-manage/:controller/:action/*", array('prefix' => 'admin', 'admin' => true));
```

This way the admin-manage url gets routed to the admin prefix and that is what you use for your controller actions:

```
admin_add(){
    //some code here
}
```

I think you should to put

```
Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin'));
```

in your core.php though, but I think it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: this works, but now I can access also admin/controller/add and admin-manager/controller/add, how can I disable admin?

Comment: You could simply set a redirect-route: `Router::redirect('/admin/*', '/admin-manage/');`. Or you redirect to a 404 page if you really need to disable the admin route, Something like that should work: `Router::redirect('/admin/*', array('controller'=>'pages', 'action'=>'error-404'), array('status' => '404'));` plus adding a 404-page in /View/Pages/error-404.ctp, not tested though.